# Open a web browser in python (Amazon EC2 server)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.com', new=2)
```

This code is working fine in local to open the web browser but the same code is not work in the AWS Ec2 server. Please help me out if am running this code in the python file the new tab is not open.

Comment: Are you running this on a Windows EC2 instance? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: There is no error the new tab is not open

Comment: Is the Amazon EC2 instance running Windows or Linux?

Comment: In Amazon EC2 Linux instance is running.

Comment: What browser were you expecting to run? How were you expecting to 'see' the web browser? Amazon Linux does not have a Graphical User Interface, nor does it have a web browser installed.

Comment: Was searching to try to figure out how to detect that no browser is present and handle accordingly. Any updates on this? The web browser module is supposed to throw and error but doesn’t seem to.